# Functions in lua tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have 
someTabe = {}

`someTabe.foo = function (x,y)
 return x + y 
end`

How can I get pint(`function"(function (x,y) return x + y end`)??? Not return result.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recover the source code of a function from inside Lua.

```
> print(someTabe.foo)
function: 0x7fed0bc091f0
```

This is telling you that `someTabe.foo` contains a function, which has been converted to internal representation stored at the address shown.

If you need to recover the source code of a function from inside Lua, you need to compile it manually with [load](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load) and then use the debug library to get the source code.

Comment: Thanks. I will try do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could could look for a decompiler online if you are just trying to see the code. However in your own code it is impossible.

Comment: I can't use decompiler. It's all for MMORPG. And I don't have sources)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get code itself, but you can get bytecode using `string.dump()`:

```
local f = function(x,y) print('AAA') end)
local bytecode = string.dump(f) -- Get bytecode of function
local f2 = load(f) -- It is copy of f, but (f ~= f2)
f2() -- prints AAA
```

Comment: Thank you) I will try today.

Comment: @ShannonMax What is your results?

Comment: I didn't make what I wanted but friend give me some good ideas. Now I use needed api and have good results)